# Refactoring IF hell

Tags: php, if-statement, authentication, refactoring

TL;DR: **What strategy can I follow to simplify request's `if` hell?**

I'm refering specifically to [**one of my github files**](https://github.com/FranciscoP/UserManager/blob/master/include.php). It's there to deal with different possible user actions. I'm trying to refactor it, but I'm not sure what's the best way. A small fraction of the code:

```
// The users returned from validating
if (!empty($_SESSION['service_connect']))
  {
  // If the service is a valid one
  if (in_array($_SESSION['service'], $UMConfig->services))
    {
    // Include the needed files.
    include $UMConfig->path . "/services/" . $_SESSION['service'] . "/verify.php";
    }
  }
// One service has set an email
if (isset($_SESSION['service_email']))
  {
  // The user is already in the database
  if (Validate::is_user($_SESSION['service_email']))
    {
    // User is logged in
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_SESSION['service_email'];
    include 'actions/login.php';
    }
  // The user is not in the database and didn't submit anythign
  elseif (empty($_POST))
    {
    // !POST
    $UMLog = "We are trying to register you with a service.";
    // Check if the popup has been submited or not
    include 'actions/service_verified.php';
    }
  // The user has submitted something with POST
  else {
    include 'actions/register_service.php';
    $UMLog = "Registering with " . $_SESSION['service'] . ".";
    }
  }

// No user was in the session but there's a user in the cookies
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['email']))
  {
  // The email is in the database
  if (Validate::is_user($_COOKIE['email']))
    {
    // If there's a token
    if (isset($_COOKIE['token']))
```

My idea right now is to simplify the code into smaller chunks and call them individually. This is the general idea of what I intend to do:

```
// Get what kind of action is needed
require 'request.php';
$action = request($_POST, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE);

if (file_exists($action_path = "actions/" . $action . ".php"))
  include $action_path;
else
  throw new Exception("Action was not valid: " . $action);
```

However, this only simplifies it slightly, as I'm only moving the if hell to 'request.php'. It has the advantage that testing is much easier in this way.

I have read how polymorphism can simplify some `if`s, however I don't think it can be applied in this case. **What strategy can I follow to simplify this `if` hell?**

EDIT: in case anyone's wondering, I have so many ifs because, besides the regular login/register, I allow users to login/register using an external *service* as facebook/google/etc, which requires more steps and makes it significantly more difficult.

Comment: For starters I see duplicate code so that would be easy to refactor.

Comment: From what you posted it isn't *hell* per-se. If you want to save a few lines, then move the logic (`$UMLog`, `$UMError` etc.) into the included file instead, but this seems longer than it is because of all the comments and the bracket styling.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, I called it a *hell* since it's difficult to follow the flow of the script because of too many `if`s. In the new "version" I proposed it'd be much easier to handle these log messages.

Comment: @PeeHaa, can you extend your comment, please?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia I see some session checking and validating thing for example.

Comment: YOu can combine the first two `if`s with `&&`. Other than that, I don't see any patterns that can be simplified. Sometimes you just have to spell out the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to follow this strategy: one function, [`request()`](https://github.com/FranciscoP/UserManager/blob/master/request.php), identifies what kind of request is being made in their simplest form. Only *identifies the action* in its simplest form and returns this.

Then, the script calling it, [`include.php`](https://github.com/FranciscoP/UserManager/blob/master/include.php), includes that action from a directory containing all actions. Each of the callable actions have many methods to verify they are valid.

**request.php:**

```
<?php

// Find if there was any action to be done with the data provided
// Importance of requests: post > session > cookie (there're no get requests)

function request($Post, $Session, $Cookie)
  {
  // The user is trying to log out
  if ($Post->logout)
    {
    return "log_user_out";
    }

  // The user wants to edit the profile
  if ($Post->edit)
    {
    return "edit_user_data";
    }

  // Someone is trying to log in
  if ($Post->login)
    {
    return "log_user_in";
    }

  // Someone is trying to log in
  if ($Post->recover)
    {
    return "recover_password";
    }

  // Someone is trying to register
  if ($Post->register)
    {
    return "register_with_form";
    }

  // First time the user attempts to connect with a service
  // This should be vefore register_with_service in case someone clicked
  // a service but later wants to register with another service
  if ($Post->service_connect)
    {
    return "service_connect";
    }

  // Someone is trying to register with a service
  if ($Post->service && $Session->service_email)
    {
    return "register_with_service";
    }

  // The service returned green light
  if ($Session->service_connect)
    {
    return "verify_service";
    }

  // The user just landed here after confirming in the service
  if ($Session->service_email)
    {
    return "service_is_verified";
    }

  // There's already a user logged in. Simply retrieve the user
  if ($Session->email)
    {
    return "retrieve_user";
    }

  // There's apparently a user in the cookies
  if (isset($Cookie['email']))
    {
    return "login_with_cookie";
    }

  // If nothing from the above was submitted
  return null;
  }
```